# Testing catch promise in Jasmine and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, promise

I have some code like this inside my component:

```
p.a().then(function(x) {
  vm.x = x;
  return p.b();
}).then(function(y) {
  if (!y) {
    return $q.reject(new Error('My Error'));
  }
  vm.y = y;
  return y;
}).catch(function(error) {
  log.error(error);
});
```

I'm able to test the success case fine:

```
it('is successful', function(done) {
  spyOn(p, 'a').and.returnValue($q.resolve('x'));
  spyOn(p, 'b').and.returnValue($q.resolve('y'));

  $ctrl = $componentController('myComponent', {
    $scope: $rootScope.$new()
  });

  p.a().then(function() {
    expect($ctrl.x).toEqual('x');
    return p.b();
  }).then(function() {
    expect($ctrl.y).toEqual('y');
    done();
  });

  $timeout.flush();
});
```

But I am not able to test the `catch` and assert the error:

```
it('fails', function(done) {
  spyOn(p, 'a').and.returnValue($q.resolve());
  spyOn(p, 'b').and.returnValue($q.resolve());

  $ctrl = $componentController('myComponent', {
    $scope: $rootScope.$new()
  });

  p.a().then(function() {
    return p.b();
  }).catch(function(error) {
    expect(error).toEqual(new Error('My Error'));
    done();
  });

  $timeout.flush();
});
```

All I get when I run the tests is:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Which means the `catch` is not even running (I tried logging something to double check).

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.. Why aren't you calling any functions on your controller `$ctrl`? What are you testing? The code in the test?

Comment: @Sonata, what do you mean? I'm calling `p.a()` and `p.b()` both return promises and after they resolve I set some data in the controller, that is what I'm testing, `vm === $ctrl`

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead of using jasmine done feature to use $rootScope.$apply();
Buy doing this angular automatically runs the promises

Remember to put the following code to inject $rootScope in the tests:

```
var $rootScope;
   beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
      $rootScope=_$rootScope_.$new();
   }));
```